# Regular Expression - Match String Pattern

Tags: java, regex

i want to print out the position of the second occurrence of `zip` in `text`, or -1 if it does not occur at least twice.

```
public class UdaciousSecondOccurence {

    String text = "all zip files are zipped";
    String text1 = "all zip files are compressed";

    String REGEX = "zip{2}"; // atleast two occurences

    protected void matchPattern1(){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while(m.find()){

            System.out.println("start index p" +m.start());
            System.out.println("end index p" +m.end());
        //  System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");

        }
```

output for `matchPattern1()` 
    start index p18
    end index p22

But it does not print anything for pattern `text1` - i have used a similar method for second pattern -

Comment: Is it just me or `text1` does not contain the "zipp" sequence?

Comment: your regex is wrong, `zip{2}` will match `zipp`

Comment: @micheal and @heroandtn3 - actually i was trying `"zip"` as a sequence and `{2}` as number of occurrences - 
now it makes sense, thanks to all the feedback down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it must match twice, rather than using a while loop I would code it like this using regex `"zip"` (once, not twice):

```
if (m.find() && m.find()) {
    // found twice, Matcher at 2nd match
} else {
    // not found twice
}
```

p.s. text1 doesn't have two zips

Comment: Of course you should xearch for just "zip" (one zip, not two)

Comment: it works this way -
`if (m.find() && m.find()){
 
   
   System.out.println("start index1 " +m.start());
   System.out.println("end index1 " +m.end());

  }
  
else {
  System.out.println("-1");
  }`

Answer (score 1):

`text1` does not match the regex `zip{2}`, therefore the while loop never iterates because there are no matches.

The expression is attempting to match the literal `zipp`, which is contained in `text` but not `text1`.  [regexr](http://regexr.com/38ugc)

If you want to match the second occurrence, I would recommend using a capture group: `.*zip.*?(zip)`

**Example**

```
    String text = "all zip files are zip";
    String text1 = "all zip files are compressed";

    String REGEX = ".*zip.*?(zip)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    if(m.find()){       
            System.out.println("start index p" + m.start(1));
            System.out.println("end index p" + m.end(1));
    }else{
        System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code it may work for you

```
public class UdaciousSecondOccurence {

String text = "all zip files are zipped";
String text1 = "all zip files are compressed";

String REGEX = "zip{2}"; // atleast two occurences

protected void matchPattern1(){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    if(m.find()){   
        System.out.println("start index p" +m.start());
        System.out.println("end index p" +m.end());
        //  System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");

    }else{
        System.out.println("-1");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {

         UdaciousSecondOccurence uso  = new UdaciousSecondOccurence();
         uso.matchPattern1();
    }   

 }
```

Comment: output is `start index1 18
end index1 22
-1`

i think it does solve most part of the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't your end index be 21 as opposed to 22?

Answer (score 0):

`zip{2}` matches the string `zipp` -- the `{2}` applies only to the element immediately preceding. 'p'.

That is not what you want.

You probably just want to use `zip` as your regex, and leave the counting of occurrences to the code around it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `String.indexOf` twice?

```
String text = "all zip files are zipped";
String text1 = "all zip files are compressed";
int firstOccurrence = text.indexOf("zip");
int secondOccurrence = text.indexOf("zip", firstOccurrence + 1);
System.out.println(secondOccurrence);
firstOccurrence = text1.indexOf("zip");
secondOccurrence = text1.indexOf("zip", firstOccurrence + 1);
System.out.println(secondOccurrence);
```

**Output**

```
18
-1
```

Comment: very nice, i always forgot `indexOf` method - first time you read java REGEX - it just creates more confusion than solving problems

Comment: @kasper_341 yes, sometimes there's easier solutions than regex :)

Answer (score 0):

The second time, statements inside `while(m.find())`  are never executed. because `find()` will not be able to find any match

Answer (score 0):

You need one or 2 pattern matching. Try with regex `zip{1,2}`,

```
  String REGEX = "zip{1,2}";
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons:
1st: Text1 doesn't contain two 'zip'.
2nd: You need to add the piece of code that would print '-1' upon finding no match. e.g. if m.find = true then print index
else print -1